# Hide Html Div in Asp.Net Page

Tags: asp.net

Trying to make this short - I have a left/right panel app where the left panel is a treelist and a click on the treelist generates some html from a db that is loaded into a literal control. This all works fine but I wanted to create some buttons and divs within the html and have have the buttons toggle the divs. Actually the divs toggle by the buttons works but I cannot get the divs to be hidden on startup. I can get this code to work as a standalone html page with jquery but when I try to get this functionality into my asp.net app I cannot get the divs to hide at startup

Master Page

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Client Page

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.hideLoad').hide();
});

$(function(){
$('.toggle').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#' + $(this).data("target")).toggle(400);
});
});//]]>

</script>
```

Html for Divs that I build as text string and put in Literal but divs are not hidden on load I also tried to write the Hide function after the divs and that didn't work

```
<div > <button class="toggle" data-target="hideDetailsCode3131Div" style="background-color:transparent;"> XXXX </button>  xxxx Text </div>

<div id="hideDetailsCode3131Div" class ="hideLoad" style="border:1px solid red; width:300px; height:100px;">

<button id="hideDetails1"  title="" class="toggle" data-target="hideDetails1Div">show box 1</button>
<button id="hideDetails2" title="" class="toggle" data-target="hideDetails2Div">show box 2</button>
<button id="hideDetails3" title="" class="toggle" data-target="hideDetails3Div">show box 3</button>
</div>

<div id="hideDetails1Div" class ="hideLoad" style="border:1px solid red; width:300px; height:100px;">
<h2>box 1</h2>
</div>
<div id="hideDetails2Div" class ="hideLoad" style="border:1px solid red; width:300px; height:100px; clear:both">
<h2>Box 2</h2>
</div>
<div id="hideDetails3Div" class ="hideLoad" style="border:1px solid red; width:300px; height:100px; clear:both">
<h2>Box 3</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could not you just add `display:none` to:

```
<div id="hideDetailsCode3131Div" class ="hideLoad" style="border:1px solid red; width:300px; height:100px;">
```

jQuery `hide()` does exactly this. Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a 2nd CSS class to the divs you want to hide "starthidden". Define this as display:none -- then remove the starthidden class when you start playing with them.